# eval() in laravel not executing the string

Tags: php, mysql, eval, laravel-5.4

My database table contains an eloquent query
[click here to see Database Table Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9KsJ.png)
.I have fetched the query from database.Now problem is that I'm unable to execute the query that is in the collection.
I have Tried **eval()** to execute the query present the collection.But **eval()** is not executing it.

```
  eval("\"$tempdata\";");
```

$tempdata contains the query that is in the database table.

Comment: The "code" you want to evaluate is a string. It **is** evaluated but it doesn't have any side effect. Use `eval("$tempdata");` instead. Even better, use `eval($tempdata);` because it's exactly the same thing.

Comment: @axiac its same,i want to execute the query fetched from database

Comment: maybe the eval function is blocked within the php.ini

Comment: @RaymondNijland its not because it is executing other strings

Comment: Any errors? you should be able to catch eval errors with `error_get_last() `

Comment: I see you are using a namespace in the database image maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018711/php-eval-and-namespace (escaping the namespace)

Comment: @RaymondNijland no error at all

Comment: @RaymondNijland if i remove namespace then it gives error "User not found" and User is the model name and namespace is also included in my controller

Comment: You don't remove the namespace laravel needs it to autoload the classes.. You escape the namespace like \\App\\User....... or use `str_replace('\', '\\') ` on that string first.

Comment: @RaymondNijland by doing so it gives sytax error of  "unknown string \....."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `return` when using eval.

Try:

```
eval("return $tempdata;");
```

Comment: Side note: Be cautious when using `eval` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval