# Eloquent query vs Simple Sql Query

Tags: laravel-5.4, eloquent

I have searched everywhere but can't find any answer.My question is that is it possible to execute an eloquent query that is stored in a variable?
In sql its so simple to execute the query,but I'm facing problems from 2 days in searching a way of executing an eloquent query that is assigned to a variable.
e.g `$query="modelname::find(1);`I have tried eval() but its not working.Actually I'm pretty new to laravel.So, I'm looking forward for your valuable answers.

Comment: Can you show your code for creating/assigning the `$query` variable? or is it related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979813/eval-in-laravel-not-executing-the-string ?

Comment: @RossWilson  yeah it's related